# Packing buttons into subframes - Python Tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I'm trying to generate a GUI which plots graphs based on a particular option selected at the top of the screen. The graphs are generated by Matplotlib. The problem I am having is getting options buttons aligned on the left hand side of the screen. Basically, I would like "Polynomial Regression" to be listed underneath "Linear Regression" but not aligned `pack(side=TOP)` as that crushes the graphs as I add more buttons.

After extensive searching, I think I need to make a frame within StartPage, pack that to the left and then pack the option buttons into this window in order with side=TOP. I'm still new to Python and very new to Tkinter, and after many attempts I can't get this to work and I've tied myself in knots. I was following a tutorial that suggested I set up the GUI windows in this way to be able to load multiple pages so I don’t have a clear-cut `root` in my code (I now don't seem to be able to find others doing it in this way). The best I can get is to pack a subframe into the main frame (pink box), but I cannot get button3 and button4 to be inside the frame without the kernel crashing.

[image]

The relevant bits of code, minus supporting functions:

```
class clientProfiler(tk.Tk): 

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "Client Profiler")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand = True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # Menu bar
        menubar = tk.Menu(container)
        filemenu = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
        filemenu.add_command(label="Save settings", command = lambda: popupmsg("Not supported yet"))
        menubar.add_cascade(label ="File", menu=filemenu)

        tk.Tk.config(self, menu=menubar)

        self.frames = {}

        frame = StartPage(container, self)
        self.frames[StartPage] = frame
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="Profiler", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack()

        boxLabel = tk.Label(self, text="Client: ", font=NORM_FONT)
        boxLabel.pack(side=TOP)

        entrybox = AutocompleteEntry(clientNameList, self)

        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Go", command=lambda: onClick())
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Linear Regression", command= lambda: linearRegress())
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Polynomial Regression", command = lambda: polyRegress())
        entrybox.pack(side=TOP)
        button2.pack(side=TOP)
        newframe = tk.Frame(self,width=200, height=1000,background="#ffd3d3")

        button3.pack(side=LEFT)
        button4.pack(side=LEFT)

        newframe.pack(side=LEFT,anchor="nw")

        canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, self)
        canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)

        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg(canvas, self)
        toolbar.update()
        canvas._tkcanvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand = True)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    ### Load the app window
    app = clientProfiler()
    app.geometry("1280x720")
    app.mainloop()
```

Is anyone able to help me get button3 and button4 into a separate frame packed to the left on StartPage? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your class StartPage, try changing this

```
button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Linear Regression", command= lambda: linearRegress())
button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Polynomial Regression", command = lambda: polyRegress())
entrybox.pack(side=TOP)
button2.pack(side=TOP)
newframe = tk.Frame(self,width=200, height=1000,background="#ffd3d3")

button3.pack(side=LEFT)
button4.pack(side=LEFT)

newframe.pack(side=LEFT,anchor="nw")
```

to this.

```
entrybox.pack(side=TOP)
button2.pack(side=TOP)

newframe = tk.Frame(self,width=200, height=1000,background="#ffd3d3")
newframe.pack(side=LEFT,anchor="nw")

button3 = ttk.Button(newframe, text="Linear Regression", command= lambda: linearRegress())
button4 = ttk.Button(newframe, text="Polynomial Regression", command = lambda: polyRegress())
button3.pack(side=TOP)
button4.pack(side=TOP)
```

It packs the buttons inside the newframe you created, which would be the buttons' master widget.

Comment: Ah ok. I can't test it for a few hours but I realise now that you place it in the new frame when the button is created, I was trying to assign it to the new frame during packing. Thanks, will give feedback when I'm at my PC.

Comment: Thank you. Frustrating that it was an easy one to solve but I still need to understand classes better. So newframe must remain a global variable in this case.